# selenium отказывается работать с циклами

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

Я недавно начал изучать селениум, и решил написать простой скрипт который находит в постах кнопку и нажимает на неё.
Для этого я реализовал простой код
Код:

```
x = 0
while True:
    post_search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@id, 'thread-')]/div/a")[x]
    print(post_search.get_attribute("href"))
    x = x + 1
```

Но тут возникла проблема, при запуске скрипта селениум просто не видит элементы
Возможные ошибки:

```
'WebElement' object is not subscriptable

 Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
```

Но если я изменяю код на подобный:

```
post_search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@id, 'thread-')]/div/a")
print(post_search.get_attribute("href"))
```

То все успешно работает и я получаю ссылку на первый элемент.

Так же если я просто реализую код по типу

```
x = 0
post_search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@id, 'thread-')]/div/a")[x]
print(post_search.get_attribute("href"))
```

То код выдает ошибку. Я пробовал всячески изменять скрипт но ничего не помогло. И поэтому решил обратиться на форум. Может подскажете что можно сделать в таком случае. Заранее большое спасибо

Answer (score 0):

С selenium не работал, но судя по [документации](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/), `find_element` находит только один элемент. А чтобы найти все элементы по заданому критерию, нужно использовать `find_elements`

И в любом случае код вида:

```
x = 0
while True:
    # обращаемся к какой-то коллекции по индексу x
    x = x + 1
```

будет выбрасывать ошибку после того, как переберёт все элементы.

Вместо этого стоит перебирать элементы циклом `for ... in ...` :

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@id, 'thread-')]/div/a")
for el in elements:
    print(el.get_attribute("href"))
```

(код примерный, на работоспособность я его не проверял)

Comment: спасибо, сейчас проверю. Но я использую try и except что бы понять когда элементы закончатся и активирую break

Comment: try и except, конечно, решат проблему. Но, всё-таки для перебора коллекции элементов есть специальный синтаксис `for ... in ...`, и лучше использовать его.